# How to create a distance matrix through a python list of dict?

Tags: python, matrix, pandas, distance

I would like to create a distance matrix for 2000 words. The matrix will be 2000 * 2000 then. Each cell is the value of how similar two words are. Now I have a list of dict with word['pair'] and word['distance'] for each pair, say word['pair'] = 'questions, answers' and word['distance'] = 0.384.

What is the best way to create the distance matrix out of this list of dict? I thought of using Python Pandas dataframe to create a dataframe first, then take the value of the dataframe. But not sure how to create such dataframe from the list of dict. Anyone can help? or better idea?

thanks a lot,

Comment: What have you attempted so far ?

Comment: I started with a brutal force solution. First I create a list of all words, then loop through the list of dict, split each dict element on ",". By finding the position of each word in the word list, I determine the position of the pair in the matrix (i,j), then assign the value to it.